# count how many diferent dates exist in a dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv dataset that has many unix timestamps line by line along with some coordinates:

```
"2018-07-13 14:04:53",20.61467382,-100.40038540
"2018-07-13 14:04:53",20.61507289,-100.40076548
"2018-07-13 14:04:53",20.61516937,-100.40073449
"2018-07-13 15:01:25",20.61535620,-100.40057307
"2018-07-13 15:01:25",20.59975566,-100.37821134
"2018-07-14 12:55:13",20.59858772,-100.37838086
"2018-07-14 13:08:06",20.59864831,-100.37822228
"2018-07-14 21:51:54",20.59862009,-100.37835681
"2018-07-15 11:53:47",20.59875168,-100.37830434
"2018-07-15 12:02:01",20.59861465,-100.37837653
```

I would like to count the number of different dates that appear. How could i achieve this?
In this case for this dataset the correct result my for loop would be 3. July 13, 14 and 15. I'm guessing i have to order it by day using pandas?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the columns is a datetime column

```
df.iloc[:, 0].dt.normalize().nunique()

3
```

Just to be sure

```
pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:, 0]).dt.normalize().nunique()

3
```

`dt` is the datetime accessor and allows you to get at the `date` attribute which is the date part of the the datetime.  Then `nunique` finishes the job by getting the number of unique values.

---

edited per @root's suggesting `dt.normalize()` instead of `dt.date`

Comment: swapping `.dt.date` with `.dt.normalize()` will probably be more performant since it doesn't cast types (i.e. `Timestamp` --> `datetime.date`)

Comment: Well that is useful.  Thanks @root

Answer (score 1):

Use a hashset!

```
import csv

with open('dates.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    data = list(csv.reader(csvfile))

unique_dates = set()
for row in data:
    date = row[0].split()[0]
    unique_dates.add(date)

print 'We have {} unique dates !'.format(len(unique_dates))
```

Answer (score 0):

A way you can achieve the same results without using `DataFrame`s is with `datetimes` and `set` comprehensions once you have read in your `csv` file

```
In [18]: import csv

In [19]: import datetime

In [21]: with open('dates.csv') as csvfile:
    ...:     data = list(csv.reader(csvfile))

In [22]: {datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').date() for row in data)}
Out[22]:
{datetime.date(2018, 7, 13),
 datetime.date(2018, 7, 14),
 datetime.date(2018, 7, 15)}
```

Comment: Overkill is relative. If your CSV file is a million rows, this solution will take 10s of seconds to complete vs half a second if you use pandas.